# "the best of the X" (might it mean several persons?)

Tags: phrase-meaning

Might it be that a phrase **"the best of the singers"** means several persons?

> They were **the best of the singers** who sang yesterday.

Might it be if they were from one band/choir, or might it be the singers who aren't from one band/choir?

Comment: Yes it can mean that, as well as meaning an individual.

Comment: I may just be that someone is using 'they' as singular. Far more common these days than even a decade ago. Without context it's impossible to say.

Comment: @gonefishin'again. Yes, it must be confusing for the non-native speaker as *were* is the plural verb but used to denote a (possible) single person. Obviously if we use non-gender neutral forms then *he/she **is** the best ...* would be correct.

Comment: My question is exactly about that phrase "the best of the singers". Not about "They were". I know that "they" can be one person.

Comment: There are several works called "The Best of the Best" (compilation albums, story anthologies, etc.) in which the first "best" clearly refers to multiple items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group is "singers who sang yesterday".  "They" is a subset of that group based on "best".

They were the best singers from the group of singers who sang yesterday.

The sentence does not indicate if the "singers who sang yesterday" were from the same band/choir, multiple bands/choirs, or simply a number of individuals.